# Input information into a string array - overwriting other parts?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have a string array that I would like to hold information input at runtime. I'm using an int var to control how many 'rows' there are in my array, but there will only ever be a set number of 'columns'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows;
    cout << "How many rows? ";
    cin >> rows;
    
    string data[rows][2];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        cout << "Column 1: ";
        cin >> data[i][0];
        
        cout << "Column 2: ";
        cin >> data[i][1];
        
        cout << "Column 3: ";
        cin >> data[i][2];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        cout << "Row " << i+1 << endl;
        cout << "Column 1: " << data[i][0] << endl;
        cout << "Column 2: " << data[i][1] << endl;
        cout << "Column 3: " << data[i][2] << endl;
    }
}
```

Expected output:
Row 1
Data 1: 123
Data 2: 456
Data 3: 789
Row 2
Data 1: aaa
Data 2: bbb
Data 3: dcc

Actual output:
Row 1
Data 1: 123
Data 2: 456
Data 3: aaa
Row 2
Data 1: aaa
Data 2: bbb
Data 3: dcc

This works for entering a single row, but if I'm entering more than one rows worth of data at a time, the last column's data is overwritten by the first column's data for the next row (so [0][2] holds the same data as [1][0]).

(Unfortunately, I am *very* new at C++ so can't figure out what's going on :()

Comment: Array indexes are origin zero. Valid indexes start at 0 and stop at size-1. That means `cin >> data[i][2];` wrote off the end of the array and into hyperspace... or into a different object in your case.

Comment: And C++ doesn't support variable length arrays.  Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Side note: `string data[rows][2];` uses a C++ compiler extension known as Variable Length Arrays. They are not part of the language Standard (as in the code won't compile on many if not most compilers) for many reasons, the most common one you'll run across is the user providing too-large a number to fit on the stack and triggering a stack overflow.

Comment: Side note: [Never ignore compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/nor1Pnq4e): They are the first line of defense against wasting time rediscovering stuff the compiler could have already told you. Very helpful so turn on more warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and turn them up loud! Optimization forces the compiler to look closer at your code to help it make faster programs and those closer looks can often reveal more problems, ergo the `-O3`. Add on `-pedantic` and the compiler will warn you about the variable Length Array problem.

Comment: The valid 2nd inexes of `data` are `0` and `1` since int size is 2. If you want it to hold 3 elements write `3` to it's size not `2` (aka `int data[...][3]`). You where overindexing. (The `...` can't be `rows` in standard `c++`, but if you sure the code will only have to work with your compiler you can let it be, it doesn't create the mistake)

Comment: Well now I feel very silly! Thank you guys for your help. I've changed the size for data to [rows][3] and don't get that error anymore, so now I'm going to make use of vectors to get the flexible 'rows' I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood correctly that the task is to store strings with text in an array that imply the use of newline hyphenation, then here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows;
    cout << "How many rows? ";
    cin >> rows;

    vector <string> page;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        string temp;
        cout << "Column 1: ";
        cin >> temp;
        page.push_back(temp);

        //test 
        temp = "Column: \n Column:2";
        page.push_back(temp);
        //end test

        cout << "Column 3: ";
        cin >> temp;
        page.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (auto & item : page)
    {
        cout << "\n page = {\n" << item<<"}\n";
    }
}
```

and yes, in a static array, you cannot specify its variable size, since the value of the variable is not known during compilation, which is why the maximum possible amount of memory is allocated for the array